# C# lambda convert

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Hello I am trying to create a filter-system for list's.

```
public void filter<T, E>(String fieldName, List<T> list, Func<T, E> rule)
{
    IList<FilterDto> filters = GetFilter(fieldName);
    foreach (FilterDto filter in filters)
    {
        if (filter != null)
        {
            if (filter.valueType == ValueType.NUMERIC)
            {
                list.Remove( this.filter(fieldName, Convert.ToDouble( o => rule(o) ) ) );
            }
            else if (filter.valueType == ValueType.DATE)
            {
            }
            else if (filter.valueType == ValueType.TEXT)
            {       
            }
            else
            {
                Log("Unkown filter comparsion");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On this line:

```
list.Remove( this.filter(fieldName, Convert.ToDouble( o => rule(o) ) ) );
```

I get the error message:

```
Error CS1660: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'bool' because it is not a delegate type
```

I have would do the real filtering on the methods something like that:

```
public bool filter(String fieldName, double? value)
public bool filter(String fieldName, int? value)
public bool filter(String fieldName, Date? value)
```

Comment: What is your `rule()` method?  What does it return?

Comment: Edit my question :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found my mistake... I have to use RemoveAll.

Like that:

```
list.RemoveAll(o => this.filter(filter, Convert.ToDouble((rule(o) as Double?))));
```

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is no overload of `Convert.ToDouble()` takes a lambda expression as an argument.  The compiler is basically picking one of the overloads -- in this case the one that takes a `bool` -- and telling you it can't convert the lambda into a `bool`.

Are you trying to pass the return value from `rule()` to be converted?  If so, just call `rule()` itself, and pass it whatever var you need to pass it (unclear from your question):

```
list.Remove( this.filter(fieldName, Convert.ToDouble(rule(yourVar))));
```

Comment: I will to the this.filter(fieldName, ...) on each element in list. How i can to this?

Comment: Also "yourVar" should be every element on the list.

Answer (score 0):

What you do does not make much sense. In your comedy (or tragedy - you choose) you have the following actors:

1. An `IList<FilterDto>`, the container of your filter objects.
2. The `filter` method who keeps everyone together.
3. A `filter` local variable who owes his existance to (1) and holds a grudge against (2), because it has the same name.
4. The `Convert.ToDouble` method who is a bit of a diva because it won't just accept anyone as its parameter's argument.
5. The `Remove` method, son of (1).
6. The `o => rule(o)` lambda expression.

Enter the `IList` (1). You iterate over it and create the `filter` (3) variable. Now comes the `Remove` method (5) which you call, probably to remove said `filter` (3), which you don't actually do; instead you remove the result of the `filter` *method* (2), which is unfortunate, because `filter` (2) does *not have* a result (alas it is `void`). However, `filter`(2) wants a `Func<T, E>` as its second argument (although not necessarily the same `T` and `E` as the original call to `filter` - the method). In comes the evil `ToDouble` (4), which has a result of `double`, which is not a `Func<T, E>` - hence your error. To make things worse, a `o => rule(o)` (6) makes its way into `ToDouble`'s (4) argument list. This now *is* a `Func<T, E>`, although `ToDouble` (4) won't be able to do much with it, because even if it tries hard, it can't convert it into a `double`.

Now how to we cut this Gordian Knot?

Well, as I see it you might want to remove an item from the `IList` (1) in case a subsequent call to your filter rule is successful. My best guess (it has to be a guess because your question is not quite clear there) is that you intent something close to this:

```
T[] itemsToRemove = list.Where( o => rule(Convert.ToDouble(o)) ).ToArray();
foreach (T item in itemsToRemove) {
    list.Remove(item);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! But i found my mistake.